# Drupal 7 default core search functionality

Tags: search, nodes

I am using drupal 7, i am in need of showing the default search functionlity, which shows the searched term content type and how many times the searched keyword occurred in the content type.

The entered keyword will be searched with site wide search and the results will show what are the content type nodes having the keyword and how many times the keyword occurred for the content type. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) offers counts and highlighting,
plus you can edit the search-result-display via UI.
to get the contenttype there, you'll need to add a custom field,
or install [search api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) and use views.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this sounds like you want to facet on the content type. The [Faceted Navigation for Search](http://drupal.org/project/search_facetapi) module allows you to do this.

After enabling the module, visit *admin/config/search/settings*, uncheck the "Node" checbox under "ACTIVE SEARCH MODULES" and check the "Faceted Navigation for Search" checkbox.

Then visit *admin/config/search/settings/facets* and enable the "Content type" facet. Once the facet is enabled, visit the core Block administration page at *admin/structure/block* and position the "Facet API: Search : Content type" appropriately.

Now you can execute a search, and you will get the following results:

[image]

Comment: Which solution did you use? It would be great if you could mark the correct answer or post your solution so others can benefit as well!